# See if pandas character column is in the string column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I want to see, by row, if values of a char column are present  in a string column.

For example, in

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'char': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D'], 
    'str': ['WCCC', 'BFC', 'GFA', 'E', <NA>]
})
```

I want to see if the 'char' column is in the 'str' column.

expected output is
`[False, True, True, False, False]`.

I am working with a large dataset.

Comment: did you mean whether a given char in one column is contained within the corresponding string in the other column?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: the canonical approach would be `df['out'] = [False if pd.isna(s) or pd.isna(c) else c in s for c, s in zip(df['char'], df['str'])]`. Don't use `apply` on `axis=1`, it's needlessly slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use zip and list comprehension with some dtype checking for NaN values like this:

```
[c in s if isinstance(c, str) & isinstance(s, str) else False for c, s in zip(df['char'], df['str'])]
```

Output:

```
[False, True, True, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a large dataset, it is better you store the information in a new column.

Added check for na and an else condition

```
import pandas as pd
df['char_in_str'] = df.apply(lambda c: c['char'] in c['str'] if
pd.notna(c['char'])
and pd.notna(c['str']) 
else False, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check(char,strng):
    # check if strng or chr not null
    if not strng or not char:
           return False
    if chr in strng:
           return True
    return False

ans = df.apply(lambda x: check(x['char'],x['str']), axis=1)
```

This will handle all the cases.